# Is there any benefit to multiple M.2 SSD drives for Audio/Video Production (hobbyist/pro-sumer) level)?

Tags: ssd, computer-building, m.2

I found this previous related question was a bit too general to receive good answers:  [Multiple vs. Single M.2 NVMe SSD](https://superuser.com/questions/1540278/multiple-vs-single-m-2-nvme-ssd)

I would like to ask more specifically about multiple M.2 drives in A/V production.

I will be building a new Windows desktop system in early 2022 (to replace an old system built on an [AMD FX-6100](https://www.newegg.com/amd-fx-series-fx-6100/p/N82E16819103962)).

The most demanding application will be video editing for music videos at a hobbyist level. Though this is not a professional studio, I still would like smooth previews, and final renders that don't need to run overnight.  I often work with amateur sources that require a lot of correction, cropping, rotation, etc., so I end up using a lot of FX plugins even when there aren't any "special" FX involved.

Before inexpensive high-capacity SSDs were available, the advice was generally to have 3 HDDs for video:

1. System/boot (This will have the editing application, and effects plugins)
2. Video source files used in the project, and the cache files generated by the edit software.  This needs non-sequential read performance of multiple video streams for compositing, etc.
3. Finished video render.  This just needs sequential write speed.

The new motherboards I'm considering will have one or two M.2 slots, though the ones with two slots tend to have only one at PCIe 4.0.

**First**: Are these reasonable assumptions?

1. I am assuming I don't really need three drives in the system with SSDs and modern CPU performance.  I expect to write the rendered video to the system drive.
2. I am assuming that the faster PCIe 4.0 M.2 slot should be for the system drive.
3. I am assuming that the slower PCIe 3.0 M.2 slot is still a better choice for a second drive than one of the 6GB/s SATA ports on the motherboard.

**Second**: Is there likely any benefit to be gained by having a separate M.2 device (in the PCIe 3.0 slot) for the video source files, or might I just as well have a single drive for the system.

Aside: I will also be doing audio recording on this system, but it will be almost exclusively tracking, which is not particularly demanding compared to the video. Audio edit, mix, and master will be done elsewhere.

Also: If you're voting to close, how about a comment explaining why?

Comment: I can't flesh out the figures to make this an answer, but as a pro sound engineer & amateur video editor of 35 years experience ;)… You're always best to have your samples/cache/proxy media well away from your OS drive Your original RAW files it doesn't truly matter as you're not using them in the edit, only at final render. Convenience would put them in the same project folder, for portability. IMO, these days render can be anywhere, it requires little in the way of resources for playback & to generate is mainly a CPU/GPU function.

Comment: Using this kind of layout, I can edit 8-cam multi-cams on a 10-year-old Mac Pro without too much hesitation. My renders are near real-time [dual 6-core Xeons still have their place;)

Comment: @Tetsujin I should clarify: By "raw video" because I just meant the unedited files in the project (what you seem to call "proxy media").  I didn't mean "RAW" files properly.  I will edit the question.  (I think different systems use different names and I'm not sure what a good generic term is.)  35 years ago, you must have been doing it with a Beta editing deck or something?  I used one of those on a high school club project in the same era.

Comment: 35 years ago I was doing it on 1" or Umatic in borrowed time at weekends in BBC TV studios ;)) I had a puter for my music - early Midi sequencer, but nothing so 'simple' for video in those days. By 'RAW' I really mean 'whatever came out of your camera'. You don't need that high-res for editing, so long as the finished product uses the high-res media.

Comment: @Tetsujin ...so you were a hobbyist yourself but had access to professional equipment.  With the edit software I've used (Vegas and the various things it's been called) the full-resolution camera-native files are still attached to the project, but the software generates preview/cache files as it goes.

Comment: Give the same a try in DaVinci - it has two proxy types in the menu [can't remember what they are now without the app in front of me, but they have 'proxy' in the title. Then in playback you can use that or even half or quarter res to keep the speeds up. It's all in the manual, but it's quite tough to explain in just a paragraph or two. And yes, I was a hobbyist video editor, but a pro audio engineer & recording artist - so I had already been in pro videos & had  friends in various pro locations I could blag from ;)) These days I work in TV/Film, but nowhere near camera or sound, ironically ;)